# Enforcing regex validated user input - what is wrong in this bash script?

Tags: bash

User should be forced to provide a valid version number (x.y.z) either as 3rd parameter or he will be prompted.

In any case I get a 'invalid arithmetic operator' error - somehow wondering whether that's the required dot? How can I fix this? What I am doing wrong?

```
valid_version_format='(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+)';
if [[ $3 -eq 0 || ! $3 =~ $valid_version_format ]]
 then
    while :
        do
        echo "Please provide a version number in x.y.z format (only figures are allowed):"
        read version_number

        if [[ "$version_number" =~ $valid_version_format ]]
            then
                break;
            else
                echo "Invalid option. Please try again."
        fi
    done

 else
 version_number="$3"
fi
```

Comment: The issue is the `$3 -eq 0` portion of your if. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but fixing it will let you move along...

Comment: He probably wants to check whether $3 is empty/missing. Correct way to do so is described in [How do I check if a variable exists](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212192/187122).

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not see it :-( - by the way the $3 -eq 0 is working as expected.